# websocket и watchdog обьединить на python

Tags: python, websocket

Есть две библиотеки websocket и watchdog мне надо обьединить их так что бы когда изменялся файл информация о нем передавалась через websocket клиенту

1 это websocket
2 watchdog

По отдельности они работают вопрос как обьединить

1

```
file = ""
async def time(websocket, path):
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + "Z"
        await websocket.send(file)
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random() * 3)
    

start_server = websockets.serve(time, "127.0.0.1", 5678)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

2

```
  if __name__ == "__main__": 
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.' 
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    file = observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt: 
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```